# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf_bert_for_sequence_classification" (type TFBertForSequenceClassification)

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

```
train = df2[:25]
test = df2[25:]

def convert_data_to_examples(train, test, text, Airline_Cat): 
    train_InputExamples = train.apply(lambda x: InputExample(guid=None, 
                                                          text_a = x[text], 
                                                          label = x[Airline_Cat]), axis = 1)

    validation_InputExamples = test.apply(lambda x: InputExample(guid=None, 
                                                          text_a = x[text], 
                                                          label = x[Airline_Cat]), axis = 1)
  
    return train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples

train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples = convert_data_to_examples(train,  test, 'text',  'Airline_Cat')

from tqdm import tqdm

def convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(examples, tokenizer, max_length=128):
    features = []
    for e in tqdm(examples):
        input_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
            e.text_a,
            add_special_tokens=True,  
            max_length=max_length,   
            return_token_type_ids=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            pad_to_max_length=True, 
            truncation=True
        )

        input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask = (input_dict["input_ids"],input_dict["token_type_ids"], input_dict['attention_mask'])
        features.append(InputFeatures( input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, label=e.label))

    def gen():
        for f in features:
            yield (
                {
                     "input_ids": f.input_ids,
                    "attention_mask": f.attention_mask,
                    "token_type_ids": f.token_type_ids,
                },
                f.label,
            )

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        gen,
        ({"input_ids": tf.int32, "attention_mask": tf.int32, "token_type_ids": tf.int32}, tf.int64),
        (
            {
                "input_ids": tf.TensorShape([None]),
                "attention_mask": tf.TensorShape([None]),
                "token_type_ids": tf.TensorShape([None]),
            },
            tf.TensorShape([]),
        ),
    )


DATA_COLUMN = 'text'
LABEL_COLUMN = 'Airline_Cat'

train_data = convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(list(train_InputExamples), tokenizer)
train_data = train_data.shuffle(25).batch(32).repeat(2)

validation_data = convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(list (validation_InputExamples), tokenizer)
validation_data = validation_data.batch(32)

from tensorflow import keras

model_auto.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5),
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy())

model_auto.fit(train_data.shuffle(25).batch(32),
             validation_data=validation_data.shuffle(25).batch(32),
             epochs=2,
             batch_size=32)
```

This is my code. Im trying to train and validate a dataset using a bert model in google colab.

```
Epoch 1/2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-5086da520d6f> in <module>
      7              validation_data=validation_data.shuffle(25).batch(32),
      8              epochs=2,
----> 9              batch_size=32)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 1403, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf_bert_for_sequence_classification" (type TFBertForSequenceClassification).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 1642, in run_call_with_unpacked_inputs  *
            return func(self, **unpacked_inputs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_tf_bert.py", line 1655, in call  *
            outputs = self.bert(
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    
        ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "bert" (type TFBertMainLayer).
        
        in user code:
        
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 1642, in run_call_with_unpacked_inputs  *
                return func(self, **unpacked_inputs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_tf_bert.py", line 767, in call  *
                batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
        
            ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
        
        
        Call arguments received:
          • self=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=int32)
          • input_ids=None
          • attention_mask=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=int32)
          • token_type_ids=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=int32)
          • position_ids=None
          • head_mask=None
          • inputs_embeds=None
          • encoder_hidden_states=None
          • encoder_attention_mask=None
          • past_key_values=None
          • use_cache=None
          • output_attentions=False
          • output_hidden_states=False
          • return_dict=True
          • training=True
    
    
    Call arguments received:
      • self={'input_ids': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=int32)', 'attention_mask': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=int32)', 'token_type_ids': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None), dtype=int32)'}
      • input_ids=None
      • attention_mask=None
      • token_type_ids=None
      • position_ids=None
      • head_mask=None
      • inputs_embeds=None
      • output_attentions=None
      • output_hidden_states=None
      • return_dict=None
      • labels=None
      • training=True
```

It has been throwing this error for quite a time. And also if it runs by luck sometimes, session is being crashed by itself saying that ram is utilised completely when not even half of the ram has been used. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.